# I keep getting blue screen - Windows 7 x64 (maybe ram?)

Tags: windows-7, memory, bsod

I have +- 5yrs old pc runnig windows 7 and I've been getting blue screen recently.

I had win 8 and I got a lof of erros with ram memory, so I reinstalled back to Win 7. (I have 2x 2 GB RAM)

To make a better image of my errors - I get them while writing email, installing nvidia driver, sound driver, running RAM test.

I got a log of my last error, could anyone tell me what is it? Should I get new RAM memories?

The last log I got:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:       6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:        1029

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   1a
  BCP1:     0000000000000403
  BCP2:     FFFFF680004FAEA0
  BCP3:     380000007594A867
  BCP4:     FFFF6680004FAEA0
  OS Version:   6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\062513-16156-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Boss\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-32156-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

[MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) Error:
[image]

Comment: it can be anything failing HDD or even a virus or driver i think it's better to test everything

Comment: The contents of the `062513-16156-01.dmp` file will tell you wonders.

Comment: @idavid it happens on every clean reinstalation, so it shouldn't be a virus.

Comment: @Ramhound how do I check the file? I'll try. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's generally easier to rule *out* causes than to rule them in.

Use [MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to test your RAM.
I seem to remember that the conventional wisdom is that you should let it run for 6 to 8 full passes with no errors before you declare it "good RAM". (The test could run indefinitely I think, if you let it.

If that doesn't fix it, you might try disconnecting all peripherals, booting into SAFE mode and then doing a ChkDsk /f  and then restarting into regular mode. If that comes up OK, then try reconnecting your peripherals.  I have a similar problem. Wasn't the RAM. Doing this Safe mode without peripherals fixes it.

Comment: It's worth noting that bad motherboard can give false positives in RAM tests. If you see RAM errors, test the same memories on other PC.

Comment: @gronostaj I'll try to find another pc thx

Comment: @user233605 - Are you sure you are getting a Windows BSOD while running Memtestx86?

Comment: @Ramhound I got the last error when I stopped memtest. This one http://tinypic.com/r/2rf78fb/5

Comment: @Lostman - Can you give me a direct like to the image itself so I can add it to your question.  I have Tinypic on my blocked listed of domains.

Comment: @Clay thanks I'll try to use MemTest86. But when I stopped memtest I got this error http://oi39.tinypic.com/2rf78fb.jpg And when I wanted to reply here on my PC I got this error tinypic.com/r/r8bfw3/5 Does it help to recognise my problem? Thanks again

Comment: @Ramhound http://oi39.tinypic.com/2rf78fb.jpg or https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1009928_10200897034501693_1020674224_n.jpg

Comment: @Lostman - All of those errors are only generated by Windows they couldn't have been generated after running memtestx86

Comment: memtest is a good start. Parameter 1 = 403. MS says this: "0x403: 
The page table and PFNs are out of sync . **This is probably a hardware error**"

Comment: @magicandre1981 yeah, I'll try to find out which part of hw it is. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Ramhound ad to the memtest comment. I got the error while running a program called memtest not the booting test program memtest86. Sorry.

Comment: So I let memtest86 run overnight and I got 4 errors. From what I learned it could mean that rams, motherboard or cpu is done. Is there any possibility to find out which part is broken? I don't have access to another computer.